# Perl Tkx module works better through SSH tunnel than direct to X server

Tags: x11, perl, fonts, mobaxterm

Trying to port an ActivePerl (on Windows) to a CENTOS Linux environment.  I was startled to find that the perl Tkx module wasn't common beyond ActivePerl, and had to be installed from CPAN, and that it really doesn't pass its tests from there

Anyway, I made a qemu VM and installed Centos 8 on it.  Then I looked to see if I could get the Tkx module working on it.

Based on advice from [this blog](https://www.kirsle.net/running-tkx-on-perl), I installed some stuff via yum, and also loaded the Tcl and Tkx perl modules from CPAN via the cpan program.  (The `PERL_DL_NONLAZY` environment thing was what inspired him to blog his solution.)

Then to test it I tried this program

```
#


BEGIN {
    $ENV{PERL_DL_NONLAZY} = 1;
}

    use Tkx;

    Tkx::button(".b",
        -text => "Hello, world",
        -command => sub { Tkx::destroy("."); },
    );
    Tkx::pack(".b");

    Tkx::MainLoop()
```

But running the program had some unexpected behaviors.  It seems to work when mobaxterm is running a ssh session to it with X11 forwarded over it.  But opening a shell in the emulated display, and running the program, where it should appear on the emulated display, instead puts a almost zero sized widget on the upper right of the virtual display.  You can drag this onto the desktop better, and drag the window sides to make it larger.  This shows a title in the window's title bar.  But where the button is, is just a dot, which apparently is the button, because if you click on it, the program ends, exactly like a click on the 'HELLO WORLD' button should work

I am at a loss to explain why this widget is showing up in an improper size on direct X11, when it seems to work OK on tunneled X11

Addendum:  Running this line from the debugger

```
 x Tkx::font_actual('TkTextFont')
```

reports a difference in the two environments

via ssh it is basically -size=>9  and under native it is -size=>0

So I will check to see that the font 'DejaVu Sans' is installed locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Deja fonts are installed in Centos 8, yet when Tk accesses them, their size is set to zero.

I don't know if there is some way from the system to set a default size for them, but as a work around, I have created some code that will change zero size Tk fonts to some sane value like so

```
#


BEGIN {
    $ENV{PERL_DL_NONLAZY} = 1;
}

        use Tkx;

        # Get the names of Tk's fonts
        my @fontnames = Tkx::SplitList( Tkx::font_names() );
    
        # resize zero sized Tk fonts to 9 points
        foreach( @fontnames)
        {
            my %actual = Tkx::SplitList(  Tkx::font_actual($_) );
    
            if ( $actual{-size} == 0 )
            {
                Tkx::font_configure( $_, -size=>9 );
            }
        }
    
        Tkx::button(".b",
            -text => "Hello, world",
            -command => sub { Tkx::destroy("."); },
        );

        Tkx::pack(".b");
        
        Tkx::MainLoop()
```